# Can the closest jquery function find child tags inside other tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML code

```
<td>
<div><p> My Txt  </p></div>
<div><a class="linkclass" >link1 </a><a> link2 </a></div>
</td>
```

Now i want that if someone click on `a.linkclass` then i alert the text inside p tag

I tried this but it didn't work

```
$(this).closest('p').text();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$(this).closest('div').prev('div').find('p').text();
```

Here p is not the ancestor of the anchor tag.. Is is nested inside a div.. So you cannot use the `.closest()` on the **p tag** directly..

The closest selector only traverses thru the ancestors of the element...

**EDIT**

You can also use the closest on the td directly.

```
$(this).closest('td').find('p').text();
```

Comment: Now it means for this first i need to know the markup. Is there any other solution. or i can find the closest td becaus ethat is always going to there